# Dropzone JS Add Thumbnail By JS Function - TypeError: this.defaultOptions is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

```
function addthumdropzone(){
    var myDropzone = Dropzone("#myDropzone");
    var myFile = {
    name: "mypdf.pdf",
    size: 987654321
};
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", myFile);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", myFile, "http://localhost/simas/data/uploads/26");
};
```

what wrong with my code? why does my firefox show the  error

```
TypeError: this.defaultOptions is undefined
```

my init, I call when document.ready

```
function dropzoneinit(){
    if(typeof Dropzone != 'undefined')
        {
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
            url: "engine/action/action.php",
            maxFileSize: 50,
            acceptedFiles: ".pdf",
            addRemoveLinks: true
        });
            myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            iddata=document.getElementById("fkirimemailiddata").value;
            $.ajax({
            url: "engine/action/action.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'what': 'deleteattacment','fkirimemailiddata' :iddata,'fkirimemailnmfile' :file.name}
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us more code ? Or create a Js fiddle for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that dropzone.js is included on page. 
It seems you missed 'new' keyword. Try this:

```
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone");
```

Comment: that already init at startup, if i declare again will error like this "Error: Dropzone already attached."

Comment: ok. See if you can create fiddle, it will help us to better understand the problem.

Comment: i still confuse using fiddle cuz i can't add php code for upload file... still error Error: No URL provided. dropzone.js:434:0
Error: Dropzone already attached.  https://jsfiddle.net/purjfus4/1/

Comment: @Artron - Try this. 1. Declare 'var myDropzone;' outside of both functions. 2. Comment out the line 'var myDropzone = Dropzone("#myDropzone");' from addthumdropzone() function. 3.In dropzoneinit() use directly 'myDropzone = new Dropzone(..)' instead of 'var Dropzone = new Dropzone(...)'